# Any way to make android app run on linux?

Tags: android, linux

I'm going to start my own carpc project. I chose linux as my OS, but I will need to use some android apps, such as navigation programs.
Is there ANY way to run android apps? The system will be on ARM.
Re-compiling programs? Virtual machine?
What do you think?

Comment: Android Emulator, which is actually virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
[AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/)

The “AndroVM” initiative aims at providing a “as good as possible” support to run Android in Virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Android Emulator`
More information can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html